# OpenCV can't acces my Raspberry Pi camera

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, raspberry-pi4

My code should use the camera to scan qr-codes and save there stored text in a csv file. I am using an Raspberry Pi Model 4b, a Raspberry Pi camera module 3 and the newest version of the Raspberry Pi OS.

```
import cv2
import csv


from datetime import date, datetime

today = date.today()
date = today.strftime("%d-%b-%Y")

now = datetime.now()
timeRN = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(-1)

detector = cv2.QRCodeDetector()


while True:
    
  
    _, img = cap.read()
    
    data, bbox, _ = detector.detectAndDecode(img)
    
   
    if(bbox is not None):
        for i in range(len(bbox)):
            cv2.line(img, tuple(bbox[i][0]), tuple(bbox[(i, 1) % len(bbox)][0]), color=(255,
                     0, 0), thickness=2)
        cv2.putText(img, data, (int(bbox[0][0][0]), int(bbox[0][0][1]) - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                    1, (255, 250, 120), 2)
        
        
        if data:
            print("data found: ", data, date, timeRN)
            
            
     
            with open('Database.csv', mode='a') as csvfile:
                
                csvfileWriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
                csvfileWriter.writerow([data, date, timeRN])    
            
                
            if data == 'red':
                pass
            if data == 'green':
                pass
        
    cv2.imshow("code detector", img)
    

    if(cv2.waitKey(1) == ord("q")):
        break
    

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

When I run the code i get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lukas/Desktop/reader.py", line 24, in <module>
    data, bbox, _ = detector.detectAndDecode(img)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.3) /tmp/pip-req-build-r02f5qx8/opencv/modules/objdetect/src/qrcode.cpp:29: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !img.empty() in function 'checkQRInputImage'
```

When I use "libcamera-hello" I get a video.

Comment: I use Raspberry Pi OS Bullseye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution at the following site.

https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=346684

Examples:

```py
img = cap.read()
img = picam2.capture_array()
```

OpenCV does not seem to support libcamera yet.